# Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined

Tags: angular

When I make a get request to get all tournaments I have paginated, I receive this kind of json.

```
{
"data": [...],
"links": {...},
"meta": {...}
}
```

Now My Component, I get all the tournaments

```
getTournaments(): void {
  this.tournamentService.all()
    .subscribe(tournaments => this.tournaments = tournaments);
}
```

My Service

```
all(): Observable<Tournament[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tournament[]>(this.listUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(tournaments => console.log(`fetched tournaments`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('all', []))
      );
  }
```

and in my view, I fetch it like that:

I can access the data in the html like that:

{{ tourna`enter code here`ments['meta'].total }}

it displays well on screen, but it also send me 2 errors in console:

```
TournamentsComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TournamentsComponent.html:13)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11940)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11312)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:11511)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11308)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
View_TournamentsComponent_0 @ TournamentsComponent.html:13
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10058
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:12166
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1647
(anonymous) @ core.js:5093
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4021
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:5093
(anonymous) @ core.js:4929
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4062
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3918
next @ core.js:4929
schedulerFn @ core.js:3712
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:253
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:191
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:129
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:53
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3704
checkStable @ core.js:4031
onHasTask @ core.js:4075
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4791
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
TournamentsComponent.html:13 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 18, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_TournamentsComponent_0 @ TournamentsComponent.html:13
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10058
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:12166
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1652
(anonymous) @ core.js:5093
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4021
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:5093
(anonymous) @ core.js:4929
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4062
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3918
next @ core.js:4929
schedulerFn @ core.js:3712
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:253
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:191
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:129
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:53
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3704
checkStable @ core.js:4031
onHasTask @ core.js:4075
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4791
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
TournamentsComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TournamentsComponent.html:13)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11940)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11312)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:11511)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11308)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
View_TournamentsComponent_0 @ TournamentsComponent.html:13
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10058
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:12166
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1647
(anonymous) @ core.js:5093
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4021
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:5093
(anonymous) @ core.js:4929
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4062
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3918
next @ core.js:4929
schedulerFn @ core.js:3712
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:253
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:191
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:129
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:53
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3704
checkStable @ core.js:4031
onLeave @ core.js:4098
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4056
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:485
target.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:2960
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2969
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:3001
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
(anonymous) @ http.js:1932
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:161
(anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:6
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:127
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:124
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:107
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
(anonymous) @ scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:176
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:161
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:55
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call @ tap.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js:17
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:158
push../src/app/components/tournaments/tournaments-index/tournaments.component.ts.TournamentsComponent.all @ tournaments.component.ts:24
push../src/app/components/tournaments/tournaments-index/tournaments.component.ts.TournamentsComponent.ngOnInit @ tournaments.component.ts:36
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline @ core.js:10097
checkAndUpdateNodeInline @ core.js:11363
checkAndUpdateNode @ core.js:11325
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @ core.js:11962
debugCheckDirectivesFn @ core.js:11922
(anonymous) @ TournamentsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
debugUpdateDirectives @ core.js:11914
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:11307
callViewAction @ core.js:11548
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:11511
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:11308
callViewAction @ core.js:11548
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:11490
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:11313
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:12204
debugCheckAndUpdateView @ core.js:11882
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges @ core.js:9692
(anonymous) @ core.js:5086
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:5086
(anonymous) @ core.js:4929
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4062
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3918
next @ core.js:4929
schedulerFn @ core.js:3712
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:253
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:191
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:129
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:53
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3704
checkStable @ core.js:4031
onHasTask @ core.js:4075
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4791
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
TournamentsComponent.html:13 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 18, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}
```

Can anyone explain me this behaviour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the error, it is from the component.html, You need to use safe navigation operator or *ngIf inorder to handle the delay of response from your asynchronous request,

Also since youw want to count the number of eleemnts in the arrya, change your template as,

```
{{ tournaments?.meta?.total }}
```

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 15 in [ {{ tournaments?.['meta']?.total }} ]

Comment: Ok, I understand basically the problem, it is for the delay...

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro good :)

Comment: but it doesnt work with an array how should I do it ? tournaments?.['meta'] is not working

Comment: {{ tournaments?.meta?.total }} I got it this way

Comment: you should juse use tournaments?.meta?.total

Comment: yep, it worked this way, please update your answer so that I accept it ! Thanks!

Comment: updated as you need

Answer (score 1):

I cant see your html but it sounds like you need to make sure the data exists before you use it. using `*ngIf`... here are a few examples

```
<div *ngIf="tournaments">
    <div *ngFor="let item of tournaments;">
        <div *ngIf="item?.meta">
            {{item.meta}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```